# Closed form for 3D Convolution Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, convolution

I'm looking for a closed form for any of the following 3D convolution integrals:

$$ A(k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3p |p|^{\nu} \exp(-\alpha|p|)|k-p|^\mu\exp(-\alpha|k-p|);$$

$$ B(k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} d^3p |p|^{\nu} \exp(-\alpha|p|^2)|k-p|^\mu\exp(-\alpha|k-p|^2).$$

Here $|\cdot|$ is just the Euclidean norm and  $\mu,\nu,\alpha$ are not necessarily integers (but let's assume the integral converges).
I know that the first integral can be solved in 1D, because it's just a convolution of Gamma distributions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.